# What is the meaning of tilde in lambda expression?

Tags: haskell, recursion, lambda, monadfix

On the 7th page of [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.15.1543&rep=rep1&type=pdf) book there is a tilde (shown by red circle in the picture below) in the definition of `toggle`. What does the tilde mean ?

[image]

Comment: They're called [lazy patterns](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html#tut-lazy-patterns)

Comment: Can you [please not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284577/are-there-any-issues-with-posting-screenshots-of-books-pages) ?

Comment: I think the image makes here clearer what is the question.